# Save Permanently Data Bloc Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, save, bloc, flutter-cubit

I'm learning Bloc, but I'm having some trouble to save the data permanently. I Have this TextFormField[image]

where it comes with a name from an API, if I update this name, it should save, and show the update name in the other screens, like the Profile Screen an Editing Profile Screen, like the images below.
[image]

enter image description here

[image]ugp5u.png

The problem is, I can save and update the name, but when I restart the app, it comes back to the previously name in the API, and I would like that this updates be saved permanently.

How can I do that?
Here's my state class

```
    class FormNameState extends Equatable {

  final String nameForm;

  //FormNameState({required this.nameForm, this.formSubmited});
  FormNameState({required this.nameForm});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [nameForm];


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'nameForm': nameForm,
    };
  }


  factory FormNameState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return FormNameState(
      nameForm: map['nameForm'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory FormNameState.fromJson(String source) =>
      FormNameState.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

Event class

```
abstract class FormNameEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class UpdateName extends FormNameEvent {
  final String nameForm;

  UpdateName({required this.nameForm});
}

class FormNameWithTester extends FormNameEvent {}
```

bloc class

```
class FormNameBloc extends HydratedBloc<FormNameEvent, FormNameState> {
  FormNameBloc(this.loginBloc) : super(FormNameState(nameForm: ''));
  final LoginBloc loginBloc;

  @override
  Stream<FormNameState> mapEventToState(FormNameEvent event) async* {
    print(event);
    if (event is UpdateName) {
      yield* _mapUpdateName(event);
    }
    /* if (event is FormNameWithTester) {
      yield* _mapUpda(event);
    } */
    //throw UnimplementedError('missingEvent');
  }

  Stream<FormNameState> _mapUpdateName(UpdateName event) async* {
    event.nameForm;
    loginBloc.add(FormEditionName(formName: event.nameForm));
    print('eventString');
    //yield state;
  }

  @override
  FormNameState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return FormNameState.fromJson(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(FormNameState state) {
    return state.toJson(state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Shared Preference to store data permanently, On app restart, you can get it back from it.